# Nothing can connect to my server, acting like it's offline (IIS/Windows)

Tags: windows, windows-10, iis, c#

I'm using IIS 10 and Windows 10, hosted on my PC at home.

The common answers I was able to find on the web don't seem to help me. Permissions are all okay, firewall port 80 is open, app pool is live. I've tried `iisreset` as well, and the W3SVC-related services are all running. When I bind the server to all unassigned on localhost:80 I can view it from there, but not from the Internet, which means the application runs fine itself.

The log files show nothing suspicious or weird either. At one point they stopped receiving connection requests, and the log just ends. HTTP 200's and then nothing. The event viewer has no errors or warnings related to W3SVC either. My external and local IP's have also not changed.

For the record, this site worked before, and only recently suddenly stopped with no changes. I don't think I did anything, but I guess it's possible? This is really boggling my mind as usually I can find any kind of solution out there, so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the IIS site mappings page? I suspect that the site is added with a hostname so is not responding to other names.

Answer (score 1):

If your site was previously working from your public IP (internet IP), but now no longer functions, and you are sure that your IP's and servers configurations have not changed, it may be an issue with your router. Check your router still has the port forwarding setting in its NAT section to point port 80 to your servers local IP.

Try connect to your IIS Server's private IP using a web browser on another machine on your private network. If this can't connect it must be a configuration setting with your IIS Server, if this can connect it's probably a problem with your router (or maybe even your ISP).

If you can't connect locally, run `netstat -a` in an elevated CMD window to check port 80 is listening, but in your situation I assume it is since you can connect via localhost. To pinpoint it to being a IIS issue and not firewall/routing issue you could stop the IIS service and run a simple application like [PortListener](http://www.rjlsoftware.com/software/utility/portlistener/) and configure it to listen on port 80, after doing that telnet to your private IP on port 80 from another machine and see if telnet connects.

Additional troubleshooting steps (but potentially unsafe):

1. If you can't connect locally - Disable your servers firewall momentarily and try connect via the private IP.
2. If you can't connect publicly - Disable your servers firewall
   momentarily and try connect via the public IP.
3. In your router's NAT configuration set all ports to be forwarded to
   your servers private IP momentarily and try connect via the
   public IP again.

Comment: Hmm, the port forwarding is still there and unchanged, and I wasn't able to connect internally through the network by going to 192.168.0.XXX:80 from a separate device. My router also does not let me disable its firewall because the port-forwarding automatically makes the exception (I guess?) but disabling the firewall on my computer completely didn't help either. Neither does pointing all the ports. Seems like it's with IIS then?

Comment: I have updated my post. Try running the netstat command to check the listening ports, or try running another application like PortListener on port 80 to see if you can connect to that.

Comment: It is common to be unable to connect internally once you forward your ports to that address.  You get around that fact by accessing through the external ip address.  Are you sure your ISP has not simply enabled a block on the port?

Comment: @Ramhound I have never experienced this, and I don't understand why this would happen, or why it would ever be desirable for this. Port forwarding is purely meant to be NAT, nothing should be getting blocked.

Comment: Using `netstat -a` showed me something very interesting: my localhost 127.0.0.1:80 is shown as "LISTENING" over TCP, but the 192.168.0.X for my PC is non-existent. I checked my firewall and router again and everything seems to be good there for the port 80 rules/forwarding, and hasn't been changed at all since before it was working. So where do you think the error is?

Comment: I believe the 192.168.X.X should only be listed once you have a connection actually established. Did you test using Port Monitor as I suggested in my post (from another machine on your LAN)? If Port Monitor Doesn't work on port 80 (after you have disabled IIS), try it on another port (and make sure you have allowed inbound traffic for that port on your machines firewall).

Comment: @JerryJackson No I did not, but I booted up my computer just now, and magically the server is online again. I didn't make any changes since checking the netstat. This is why I think it's IIS, because it's just so randomly spotty. I'm certain, due to the other times the server has died, that if I were to restart my PC now, the site would go down and stay down again inexplicably. Ever hear of anything like this?